# Git-TFS giving "not a recognized identity" trying to create shelveset

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I'm using [git-tfs](https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs), and much of its functionality works fine. I can pull, and I can use the checkintool. But I can't create shelvesets. When I try to `git tfs shelve ShelveSetName`, I get this error:

> TF14045: The identity MYDOMAIN\Joe White is not a recognized identity.

It looks like, for some bizarre reason, `git tfs shelve` is trying to authenticate against my given name ("Joe White", space included) instead of my user name, so of course it fails to authenticate because user names can't have spaces in them.

How can I get `git tfs shelve` to authenticate correctly, i.e., using my currently-logged-in Windows user credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your tried using the --username option when shelving? Or turned on debug with the -d option?  If that doesn't work it's likely a bug.  git-tfs is still fairly new and the authentication options got reworked a fair bit recently and it's possible the shelve command got overlooked now that it's not the main approach for committing.

If you can't get it to work log an issue with the debug log on the main github site and one of the contributors will no doubt try and fix it for you quickly.

Comment: I tried appending `--username myusername`, but that just displayed the help content (same output as `git tfs help shelve`), so it must have been an unrecognized option. That documentation doesn't mention a `--username` option, btw. I also tried `--username=myusername`, but that said `No TFS parents found!`, which seems odd given that I can use checkintool just fine. Any further suggestions, or should I write this up as a bug?

Comment: Put it up as a bug.  I'll also check the code when I get a chance.

Comment: Written up: https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs/issues/81. According to the comments there, it's fixed in the latest code, but there isn't an updated binary yet.

Comment: Is the fixed binary available now? I'm getting `No TFS parents found!` while doing `git tfs checkintool --build-default-comment`